# My Angular 7 component is connected to a data source, but no data is displayed

Tags: angular, service, components

I'm using Angular 7 with a Rails 5 back-end.  I'm having trouble getting my front-end to display the data stored in my component.  Here's a shared service I've created, src/shared/currency.service.ts,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CurrencyService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  index() {
    return this._http.get('api/currencies').map(r => r);
  }

  refresh() {
    return this._http.get('api/refresh').map(r => r);
  }
}
```

Here's my src/app/app.component.ts file ...

```
import { CurrencyService } from './../shared/currency.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  currencies: any;
  title = 'app';
  apiStatus: string;
  constructor(private _currencySrv: CurrencyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._currencySrv.index().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies);
  }

  refresh() {
    this._currencySrv.refresh().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies);
  }

}
```

I have this as my src/app/app.component.html file ...

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<ul>
  <li ngFor="let currency of currencies">
    <div>{{currency.name}}</div>
    <div>{{currency.country}}</div>
    <div>{{currency.rate / 100}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<button (click)="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

But despite the fact I can see my dev tools network panel make the http://localhost:4200/api/currencies call returning data, nothing is visually displayed on my page when I visit http://localhost:4200 (except a single dot).  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an error in the console which says something like "cannot read 'name' of undefined". That's because you are trying to render the list before you get the data. Wrapping your list into `<ng-container *ngIf="currencies?.length">` should help. Or use the async pipe in the template. Link to the docs https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Or you can set the initial value of the `currencies` as an empty array `[]`

Note: it's not a good practice to use `any`, try to avoid it, so it's safer and you have more control over your variables.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm somewhat new to this so I first wanted to try the simplest of your suggestions -- I changed "currencies: any;" to "currencies = [];" but then this line, "    this._currencySrv.index().subscribe(currencies => this.currencies = currencies);" produced the error, "error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'"

Comment: That means the index() method returns an object instead of array